PackageManager.queryIntentActivities returns empty on random devices
I'm trying to gather the available browsers and specifically the customtab compatible browsers on an android device.
The weird behavior is that on some devices, for instance two galaxy S20FE, one will have the below code working perfectly and the other one won't return any browser.
Weirder: a non working device can work again via an update or randomly it will just run again after some times by itself.
And the running device can stop working too between two app launches.
It seems that it mostly affects samsung devices.
Regarding the customtabs compatibility, it is also non consistent. Chrome is a compatible browser. But sometimes, I can get chrome threw getBrowsers() but I can't get the customtab compatibility flag.
To do that I use this code :
private List<ResolveInfo> getBrowsers(PackageManager packageManager) {
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent()
            .setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
            .setData(Uri.fromParts(SCHEME_HTTP, "", null));
        List<ResolveInfo> resolvedActivityList;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            resolvedActivityList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(activityIntent, PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags.of(PackageManager.MATCH_ALL));
        } else {
            resolvedActivityList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(activityIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                List<ResolveInfo> allActivityList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(activityIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL);
                resolvedActivityList.addAll(allActivityList);
            }
        }
        return resolvedActivityList;
    }

On the result I use packageManager.resolveService to check if the browser has a customtab flag:
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
serviceIntent.setAction(ACTION_CUSTOM_TABS_CONNECTION);
serviceIntent.setPackage(packageName);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
    return packageManager.resolveService(serviceIntent, PackageManager.ResolveInfoFlags.of(PackageManager.MATCH_ALL)) != null;
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    return packageManager.resolveService(serviceIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL) != null;
} else {
    return packageManager.resolveService(serviceIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY) != null;
}

I have also included the require < queries > in manifest. I try to remove it, it does not seem to change anything:
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
    </intent>
</queries>

What I tried:
On a non working device I duplicated my app by changing the appId in build.gradle, the cloned app was working while the original was not. Was fixed by forcing the update which is not always working.
Expectation:
Code is running correctly all the time.
Can anyone help me please ? :)

I would start by using an actual valid Uri in getBrowsers(). If SCHEME_HTTP resolves to http, your Uri would appear to be http://, and that Uri is invalid.

I have the same issue: I query all the activities that handle ACTION_SEND intents and some devices only show limited options (Nearby Share, Bluetooth) but not expected apps (Gmail, Yahoo, Whatsapp...). It seems to be mostly on Samsung devices with Android 13. Restarting the device sometimes help, but not always.

Hi, I have tested by adding the full URL, it is unfortunately not working either.
Exactly the same behavior as guillaume-tgl, sometimes restarting helps.

Note: This question is referenced by AppAuth-Android#1052

Did anyone manage to fix this issue? I'm facing it as well. A couple of users reported it to me and all of them had Samsung phones with Android 13 and OneUI 5.
